# Выполнение методов сервиса из связанном Activity. Android

Tags: android, activity, kotlin, android-service

Собственно код.

Кусок кода сервиса:

```
class TestService : Service()
    inner class SigDataServiceBinder : Binder() {
        val service: TestService
            get() = this@TestService
    }

    fun test() {
    // что то делаем долгое
    }
```

Actyvity привязалась к сервису. И вызывает "долгий" метод test()

```
class TestServiceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var boundService: TestService? = null

    // .....

    fun callServiceMetod() {
       boundService?.test()
    }
```

Такой вызов test() произойдет в главном потоке (который затормозит обработку UI) ?
Если да, то есть ли смысл делать так

```
fun test() {
     Handler(mainLooper)
                .post {
                 // что то делаем долгое
                 }
}
```

Как вы порекомендуете обрабатывать долгие операции?

Comment: IntentService, HandlerThread, AsyncTask, Kotlin Coroutines... Вариантов много, берите что нравится. Раз у вас котлин, то я бы рекомендовал [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html)